# Dockerfile uses "npm install" in a build step, but npm run in CMD fails

Tags: docker, dockerfile

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:9

RUN apt-get update -yq \
&& apt-get install curl gnupg -yq \
&& curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash \
&& apt-get install nodejs -yq \
&& apt-get clean -y

ADD . /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 2368
VOLUME /app/logs

CMD ["npm", "run". "start"]
```

Now

```
docker build -t d_npm  .
```

it compile with no errors

But

```
docker run -d -p 2368:2368   d_node
```

fails with this message

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "npm": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: I assume the `.` instead of a `,` on the CMD line is a typo in your question? Because that would cause a different error message than the one you showed if it were present in your real Dockerfile. (In particular, it would cause Docker to run `sh -c '["npm", "run". "start"]'`, because when a CMD isn't valid JSON it assumes it's a shell command line).

Comment: ..._in general_, on the "how to debug" original question -- start an interactive shell, and poke around. Make sure there's an npm executable; check where it's located, make sure that location is in the PATH, etc.

Comment: Also, should the two image names `d_npm` and `d_node` be the same?